# Java Web Application. Problems in locating images

Tags: java, html, image, web

I'm making a java web app, and I want it to display an image. However, it doesn´t find my image.

I've made a folder in `/src/main/resources/images`

Also, in the `.jsp` file, I´ve tried with the following sentences.

```
 <img src="/src/main/resources/images/Head.png"> </img>

 <img src="< c:url value='/src/main/resources/images/Head.png'/>"> </img>
```

Is there anything bad I'm doing?

Thanks

Edit:

The path of mi `.jsp` file is `/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/welcome.jsp`

You can find the web app code in https://github.com/Santi-7/hello

Comment: Add to your qestion the path to your `.jsp` file

Comment: Can you provide the code of your web app or a link to a public repository where the code of your web app is?

Comment: The path is /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/welcome.jsp

Comment: Of course, the web app code is in https://github.com/Santi-7/hello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is a [Spring Boot app](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/). I think that you can also try to use the facilities provided by Spring Boot for serving static content. Anyway, you are doing it right now because you are using *webjars* for css and js libs!!! Be consistent with the tech that you are using.

Comment: I've added a new post to discuss this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798972/java-web-application-spring-boot-locating-images

Answer (score 1):

The structure of a `.war` file is as follows:

```
/
    /WEB-INF
        /lib
        /classes
    /META-INF
```

Now, your application has the following structure (I assume, given the folder structure, you are using Maven)

```
/
    /src
        /main
            /java
            /resources
            /webapp
```

Now, the Maven war plugin will copy everything in the classpath to `/WEB-INF/classes` during compilation - this is `/src/main/java` and `/src/main/resources` by default.

The crux of the matter is that **nothing under `/WEB-INF` or `/META-INF` can be accessed** by requests - this is for security as otherwise someone could simply download `/WEB-INF/web.xml` for example.

So, in order to add a resource that is accessible by a browser, you need to place it into `/src/main/webapp` - this will become the root of the application.

So if you place `Head.png` into `/src/main/webapp/images` then in the JSP you would use:

```
<c:url value='/images/Head.png'/>
```

In short, you need to read up on how the directory structure of a `.war` works and how that relates to your code.

Comment: Worked! But i had to use <img src="/images/Head.png" />

Comment: @SantiGil I wouldn't do that unless you deploy your application as `ROOT` - otherwise you application will be at `context` so the full URL will be `/context/images/Head.png` and your application will no longer work. This is why the [`c:url`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_url_tag.htm) exists - to automatically add in the context.

Answer (score 0):

The path to the image must be relative to the path to the .jsp file.

Because the path to your image is: `/src/main/resources/images/Head.png`, and the path to your jsp file is: `/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/welcome.jsp`, in your image tag you need to write:

```
<img src="../../../resources/images/Head.png" />
```

The `../../../` is for getting out from the `jsp` folder to the `main` folder, and the `resources/images/Head.png` is the path from the `main` folder to the image.

Comment: Thanks, i had to use a relative path to the .jsp file's path as you said.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this at all. It's not only fragile but likely not to work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody, i could resolve my problem.

Changes I made:

> So, in order to add a resource that is accessible by a browser, you need to place it into /src/main/webapp - this will become the root of the application.

Now, my images are in `/src/main/webapp/images`.

> The path to the image must be relative to the path to the .jsp file.

Now, the sentence of my `.jsp` file is

`<img src="images/Head.png" />`

Edit [1]:

¡ I made a mistake. The path to the image is relative to the /webapp classpath !

Comment: In your question you wrote the path to your images is: `/src/main/resources/images`. I don't know if you made the mistake here or in your question but you'll need to fix that.

Comment: I had that path in the beginning, but as Boris the Spider suggested, i changed this path to /src/main/webapp/images