# How do I use "/images" path in Spring boot Rest controller with security?

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have a Spring boot REST service (spring-boot-starter-parent:1.3.2) that exposes some endpoints using RestController defined methods. I am also using Spring security. Everything works fine until I try to define a controller method that is mapped to "/images". When I try to access this api path I get the following error. By debugging I can see that my controller handler is being mapped, but the preauthorize filter is not being called (it is called properly for other mappings). I have set the following properties, but with no change. How do I fix this so that I can use "/images"?

```
spring.resources.add-mappings=false
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/hide-me/**
```

Error:

```
    "exception": "org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException",
    "message": "An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext",
```

Code:

```
@RestController
@PreAuthorize(value = "hasAnyAuthority('SOMEUSER')")
public class ImageController {
  ...
  @RequestMapping(value = { "/images/{imageId}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
  @ResponseBody
  public Image getImage(@PathVariable UUID imageId) {
    return imageDataService.getImage(imageId);
  }
  ...
```

If I change the mapping to the following then it works just fine.

```
  @RequestMapping(value = { "/image/{imageId}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
  @ResponseBody
  public Image getImage(@PathVariable UUID imageId) {
    return imageDataService.getImage(imageId);
  }
```

I'm thinking that the config for static resources has a default entry that tells Spring security to ignore the "/images" path for the preauth filter. I'm debugging around trying to figure out where that might be overridden.

Comment: Can you tell us which `@RequestMapping` are you using (at class level and/or at method level)? Which is the URL you are trying to access? According to your Spring Security configuration, what makes the `/images` path different from any other paths of your API?

Comment: See my code sections. I'm trying to use @RequestMapping(value = { "/images/{imageId}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET).

Answer (score 2):

SpringBoot by default use some paths

> private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
>         "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/",
>         "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/" };

https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot

And one of this paths is /images

[Java Web Application. Spring Boot. Locating Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798972/java-web-application-spring-boot-locating-images)

Also you have the following restrictions when usind SpringSecurity

> The basic features you get out of the box in a web application are:
>
> An AuthenticationManager bean with in-memory store and a single user
>   (see SecurityProperties.User for the properties of the user). Ignored
>   (insecure) paths for common static resource locations (/css/**,
>   /js/**, /images/**, /webjars/** and **/favicon.ico). HTTP Basic
>   security for all other endpoints. Security events published to
>   Spring’s ApplicationEventPublisher (successful and unsuccessful
>   authentication and access denied).

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/

Common low-level features (HSTS, XSS, CSRF, caching) provided by Spring Security are on by default.

Comment: I saw those docs, but found it hard to believe that there isn't a way to easily turn it off when creating a rest service.

Comment: You can override the configuration look at this project https://github.com/bclozel/spring-resource-handling

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure, that security is done for every request. This can be done using the following `SecurityConfiguration`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```